# FreeMarker ?replace multiple values

Tags: replace, freemarker

Is it possible to replace multiple values in a FreeMarker template?
For example, if I want to replace "a" and "b" with "c", I have to do this:

```
${event.EventTitle?replace('a','c')?replace('b','c')}
```

but I'd rather do something like this:

```
${event.EventTitle?replace("'a','b'",'c')}
```

Any chance FreeMarker has this capability?

I'm ultimately trying to replace all special characters ($,.,@,&,etc) with dashes, so feel free to suggest an easier way to do that.

Comment: I came to the this question. When you want to replace the elements in a list, you can use `replace` with `list` together.

Comment: Using a list for a replace ? will that work!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use a regular expression for this:

```
${event.EnventTitle?replace('a|b', 'c', 'r')}
```

Note the `'r'` at the end.

Comment: `'r'` stands for regular expression

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function like this:

```
<!--FUNCTION-->
    "<#function clearString replaceString>
        <#return replaceString?capitalize?replace("Á","A")?replace("á","a")?replace("à","a")?replace("â","a")?replace("ã","a")?replace("ä","a")?replace("É","E")?replace("é","e")?replace("è","e")?replace("ê","e")?replace("ë","e")?replace("Í","I")?replace("í","i")?replace("ì","i")?replace("î","i")?replace("ï","i")?replace("Ó","O")?replace("ó","o")?replace("ò","o")?replace("ô","o")?replace("õ","o")?replace("ö","o")?replace("Ú","U")?replace("ú","u")?replace("ù","u")?replace("ü","u")?replace("û","u")?replace("ñ","n")?replace("ý","y")?replace("&amp;","e")?replace("ç","c")}>
    </#function>"   
<!--/FUNCTION-->

<!--I assign a value to a variable just to test-->
        <#assign name="Mãtheus">
<!--I call the function passing the variable I want to clear-->
        ${clearString(name)}
```